# How to format string to custom date (YYYY-mm-dd) in TSQL?

Tags: date, t-sql

I table with a varchar column which stores date in YYYY/MM/DD. I want to get the year value and format the date.

Actual Data:  2020/11/25

Expected: 2020/01/01

```
 Select   YEAR(convert(datetime, empDate, 111)) FROM  empTable; ==> returns 2020

 Select  CAST((YEAR(convert(datetime, empDate, 111))) + "01" + "01" ) as Date) FROM  empTable;
```

Error:

```
Invalid column name '01'.
Invalid column name '01'.
```

I tried casting mm and dd values, but that throwing other errors. Thaks for your  help.

Comment: *"I table with a varchar column which stores date "* this is the real problem. Fix your design, store dates as a `date` and then *format* the value in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a string you could simply concatenate the month/day to the year and then cast:

```
declare @notanActualDate varchar(10) = '2020/11/25';

select Convert(date, Concat(Left(@notanActualDate, 4), '0101'));
```